# Mordell-Weil groups of Elliptic Surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-surfaces

Consider the moduli space $M_d$ ($d\geq 2$) of relatively minimal Jacobian elliptic surfaces $S\to\mathbb P^1$ with $p_g(S)=d$.  This was constructed by Miranda (1981) using Weierstrass form and the techniques of Geometric Invariant Theory.

Let $R\subset M_d$ be the divisor consisting of surfaces with a reducible fiber.  Let $W$ be the locus of surfaces with non-trivial Mordell-Weil group.  Cox proved (1990) that $W\cap (M_d-R)$ is a countable union of codimension $d$ subvarieties.

My question is about $W\cap R\subset R$.  Is this known to be a proper inclusion?  Do we have any examples of (non-K3) elliptic surfaces with reducible fibers and trivial Mordell-Weil group?

Comment: Are you saying that you know examples that are K3 surfaces, but you want other examples?  If you know examples of $S\to \mathbb{P}^1$ with $S$ a K3 surface, then you also know examples where $S$ is not a K3 surface.  Just consider base change by a general morphism $\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $>1$.  There are enough moduli of such morphisms that if there were "extra" sections after every such base change, then specializing those sections would give "extra" sections of the original elliptic surface.

Comment: @JasonStarr:  Yes, there exist K3 examples by the Torelli theorem.  By "specializing extra sections," you are alluding to the technique of Graber-Harris-Starr?  I'm actually primarily interested in the the case $d=2$, which cannot be obtained from a K3 by base change.

Comment: There are also rational elliptic examples!  It seems like this produces examples in all degrees by base change and specialization.